# How to avoid nested callbacks in Vert.x?

Tags: callback, vert.x

I have some code like this, use vertx-jdbc-client

```
 client.getConnection(res -> {
            SQLConnection connection = res.result();
            connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_User", res2 -> {
                connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_Book", res3 -> {
                    System.out.println(res2.result().getRows() + "--" + res3.result().getRows());
                });
            });
        });
```

`Future` ? `RxJava` ? you can use any one you like , just avoid nested callbacks, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by _resolve callback_.

Comment: @tsegismont flat the method call

Answer (score 0):

Futures works exactly same like JavaScript promises. Create a method which will return `Future<T>`, do your async call in this method. When your async is done, just call `future.complete(<T>)`

```
Future<JsonObject> getUsers(){
    Future<JsonObject> future = Future.future();
    client.getConnection(res -> {
        SQLConnection connection = res.result();
        connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_User", res2 -> {
            connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_Book", res3 -> {
                JsonObject rows = new JsonObject().put("res2",res2.result().getRows()).put("res2",res3.result().getRows());
                future.complete(rows);
                // In exception block, you can add
                // future.fail(Throwable);
            });
        });
    });
    return future;
}
```

RX works on stream. So the above code in RX will become:

```
Observable<JsonObject> getUsers(){
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        client.getConnection(res -> {
            SQLConnection connection = res.result();
            connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_User", res2 -> {
                connection.query("SELECT count(1) FROM T_Book", res3 -> {
                    JsonObject rows = new JsonObject().put("res2",res2.result().getRows()).put("res2",res3.result().getRows());
                    subscriber.onNext(rows);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                });
            });
        });

    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.NONE);
}
```

With RX APIs

```
Observable<Long> userCount = mongoClient.rxCount("users", query).toObservable();
Observable<Long> booksCount = mongoClient.rxCount("books", query).toObservable();


Observable
        .zip(userCount, booksCount, (userRes, booksRes) ->
                new JsonObject().put("user",userRes).put("books",booksRes)
        )
        .subscribe(objects -> {
            System.out.println(objects.getString("user"));
            System.out.println(objects.getString("books"));
        });
```

I have used `mongoClient`, but you can do same with `sqlClient`.

Comment: I also see the nested call , can flat the method call ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that